# Travel Distance Calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance-matrix

What is the best method calculating travel distance between destination and point layer in QGIS when using OSGB 1936 / British National Grid coordinate reference system?

Comment: As far as I am aware distance calculations in QGIS all run of the Ellipsoid that is set in the project properties. The default and best for British National Grid is considered to be Airy 1830.

Comment: thank you! In your experience what would be the best tool / method to calculate distance between a layer of points and destination?

Comment: In QGIS I would always use the Distance Matrix - depending on your desired output you can adjust the matrix type in the tool settings to get the desired result.

Comment: Just be aware the distance matrix works best with points to points - if you are running it to other vector types then I believe it assumes the centroid as the node.

Comment: Both layers are point shapefiles. Which of the three options gives the best result in terms of accuracy? Would the distance calculated by Distance Matrix be the same as distance measured on the map? Thanks so much!

Comment: They all give the exact same accuracy, the only thing they change is the output matrix. Yes it should be the same so long as you are measuring in the same units (e.g. meters, miles or km...). QGIS will use the CRS and reference ellipsoid for all it's measurements with native tools. 3rd party plugins may not.

Comment: Does that mean that the distance matrix calculates the actual distance rather than crow flies distance?

Comment: It is great circle distance based of the ellipsoid - it is not travel distance by road. Might be good if you edit your original question to make it clearer as to what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a tool that calculates travel distance on the road?

Comment: That is a totally different question that you will need to ask or edit this question to explain exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question of "what's the *best* method" is entirely subjective and specific to your situation. The best way to answer this question, in my opinion, is for you to research the different methods and try out the one(s) that seem to best fit your needs. Here's some information to help you get started.

As was discussed in the comments above, calculating *straight-line distance* ("as the crow flies") is a relatively simple task, and there are many ways to do this in QGIS (eg Distance Matrix).

On the other hand, calculating *travel distance* is more complicated. This is also called

- "routing"
- "network analysis"
- "shortest path"
- "path finding"

With these search terms you will find many sources that explain the different methods available in QGIS. For example:

- ORS Tools plugin

  > ORS Tools provides access to most of the functions of openrouteservice.org, based on OpenStreetMap. The tool set includes routing, isochrones and matrix calculations, either interactive in the map canvas or from point files within the processing framework. Extensive attributes are set for output files, incl. duration, length and start/end locations.
- Online Routing Mapper plugin

  > Generate routes by using online services (Google Directions, Here, MapBox, YourNavigation, OSRM etc.)
- GRASS tool `v.net.distance`. This tool requires a road network layer. You can obtain roads from Open Street Map, the [British Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-roads.html) or from other sources (see [Open Data Stackexchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeospatial%5D%20road%20network)).